# Is there a limitation in number of text plotted using matplotlib in Power BI?

Tags: python, matplotlib, powerbi

I'm trying to use Power BI to show my work progress. It's plotted using matplotlib and the code worked when I ran it in pycharm. When I copy my code to python power BI, it crashed and the data can't be shown.

Here's my code to plot the text:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Power BI\Bored Pile.xlsx',"Sheet1")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def plotting(title):
for i in range(len(dataset.index)):
    if dataset.at[i,'X'] != None:
        x = dataset.at[i,'X']
        y = dataset.at[i,'Y']
        ax.text(x+0.25,y,dataset.at[i,'No'],fontsize=6, va = 'center', ha='center', clip_on=True)

        if type(dataset.at[i,'Status']) != pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType:
            dataset['Finish Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Finish Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            if dataset.at[i, 'Finish Date'] != 'NaT':
                ax.text(x, y-0.2, dataset.at[i,'Finish Date'], fontsize=6, va = 'center', ha='center', clip_on=True)`
plt.show()
```

Here's the data plotted in pycharm
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwiwM.png

Here's my data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-PUwCSDT6fOC-_SBb6WumO4mty8DgGjp/view?usp=sharing

Is there any limitation in number of text plotted using matplotlib in Power BI?